# How to fix the packet exchange monitored with wireshark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, wireshark, packet

I am trying to send the messages shown to the device with the IP address '10.5.33.16' from my pc '10.5.33.42'. The purpose of these commands is to try to get access to a value that the external device has, and I'm trying to receive it with my program with no such luck.

```
import socket

min_msg = ':CALCulate:MARKer:FUNCtion:TYPE MINimum\n'
exec_msg = ':CALCulate:MARKer:FUNCtion:EXECute\n'
y_msg = ':CALCulate:SELected:MARKer:Y?\n'

def data_send_receive(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host,port))

    commands = [min_msg, exec_msg, y_msg]          
    i = 0
    for command in commands:
        s.send(bytes(command,'utf-8'))
        i += 1

        try:
            data = s.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
            if(len(data) > 0):
                print("Received data!\nminimum is:", data)
                return True
            else:
                print("No blocking, but no data in packet.")
                return False
        except socket.timeout as e:
            print(e)
            return False
        finally:
            s.close()

if data_send_receive('10.5.33.16',5025) is True:
    pass
else:
    raise Exception("Could not receive data.")
```

[Actual packets on top, expected packets on bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31TV2.png)

There are too many packets being exchanged, and the length is wrong for [PSH, ACK] command in the 'actual packets' image. My code is supposed to connect to a TCP socket, send the commands [min_msg, exec_msg, y_msg] then check if there is a response from the external device, '10.5.33.16'. If the no data is received or data is blocked, it stops. My final goal is for the packets received to match the 'Expected packets'.

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol, it doesn't preserve message boundaries. You can't assume that if you call `send()` 3 times the receiver will get them in 3 different `recv()` calls. You need to implement a protocol to determine message boundaries.

Comment: Don't use `while i < len(commands)`, use `for command in commands`.

Comment: Since I'm using TCP, I need to create a protocol for determining message boundaries?

Comment: That's exactly what I said? For instance, HTTP, SMTP, and FTP use commands terminated with newline.

Comment: Should I use socket.getaddrinfo for the protocol

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with it. There's nothing that does this automatically, you have to code it explicitly into the applications. For instance, concatenate a newline onto the command, and then in the receiver you search for newline characters in the received data.

Comment: I updated it, but I can't check if the data is received on the other device. I can check it in wireshark. I have to have all of my code on this PC.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about how the packets appear in Wireshark. The operating system can combine arrange the data in packets however it wants, since only the stream of bytes matters.

Comment: How does using newline determine message boundaries? I just need the commands sent in order, then get a response.

Comment: That was just an example of a common method. Another possibility is to prefix messages with their length. Or you can send it in a structured format like XML or JSON.

Comment: All that matters is that the sender and receiver agree on the format so the receiver can detect where the message ends.

Comment: How would I send it in a structured format like you mentioned

Comment: Something like `s.send(json.dumps(commands).encode('utf-8'))` will send all the commands as a JSON array.

Comment: what would be the right way to decode it after receiving? It doesn't hang or block but I get 'No blocking, but no data in packet.' message which I wrote so the program wouldn't keep running.

Comment: The receiving end uses `json.loads()`. This is basic Python stuff.